# Type Lambda's in Scala: why is the extra parentheses needed in a declaration?

Tags: scala, types, grammar

**Intro:**

According to my understanding the type declaration `{type λ[α] = Either[A, α]}` stands for any type which has an other type `λ[α]` as its member (in the exact same sense as methods are members of a class). This is a structural type, namely its structure is that it has the type alias declaration `λ[α]` as its member.

On the other hand, `({type λ[α] = Either[A, α]})#λ` refers to **only** `λ` due to the type projection via `#`.

**Question:**

Why is the parentheses needed around `{type λ[α] = Either[A, α]}` when doing the type projection ?  Why not just {type λ[α] = Either[A, α]}#λ ?

In other words, **what is the exact parse tree** for `({type λ[α] = Either[A, α]})#λ` according to the [Scala Type declaration grammar](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html) (see below) ?

Why is `{type λ[α] = Either[A, α]}#λ` not a correct "sentence" in this grammar ?

```
  Type              ::=  FunctionArgTypes ‘=>’ Type
                      |  InfixType [ExistentialClause]
  FunctionArgTypes  ::=  InfixType
                      |  ‘(’ [ ParamType {‘,’ ParamType } ] ‘)’
  ExistentialClause ::=  ‘forSome’ ‘{’ ExistentialDcl
                             {semi ExistentialDcl} ‘}’
  ExistentialDcl    ::=  ‘type’ TypeDcl
                      |  ‘val’ ValDcl
  InfixType         ::=  CompoundType {id [nl] CompoundType}
  CompoundType      ::=  AnnotType {‘with’ AnnotType} [Refinement]
                      |  Refinement
  AnnotType         ::=  SimpleType {Annotation}
  SimpleType        ::=  SimpleType TypeArgs
                      |  SimpleType ‘#’ id
                      |  StableId
                      |  Path ‘.’ ‘type’
                      |  ‘(’ Types ‘)’
  TypeArgs          ::=  ‘[’ Types ‘]’
  Types             ::=  Type {‘,’ Type}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You also need to consider

```
CompoundType    ::=  AnnotType {‘with’ AnnotType} [Refinement]
                  |  Refinement
Refinement      ::=  [nl] ‘{’ RefineStat {semi RefineStat} ‘}’
RefineStat      ::=  Dcl
                  |  ‘type’ TypeDef
                  |
```

#### informal description

`#` can only follow a `SimpleType`, but `{type λ[α] = Either[A, α]}` is a `Refinement`, which ultimately is a `Type`.

The only way to get a `SimpleType` from a generic `Type` is to surround it with parenthesis.

#### formal derivation

```
SimpleType
'(' Types ')' '#' id
'(' Type ')' # id
'(' InfixType ')' # id
'(' CompoundType ')' # id
'(' Refinement ')' # id
'(' '{' RefineStat '}' ')' # id
'(' '{' 'type' TypeDef '}' ')' # id
         ...
({ type λ[α] = Either[A, α] })#λ
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the illuminating and precise answer !

Comment: Btw, is that extra | at the bottom of RefineStat not a typo ?

Comment: I mean, a typo in the Scala language specs?

Comment: it could simply mean an empty declaration, not sure though

Answer (score 8):

`#` requires `SimpleType`:

> `SimpleType ‘#’ id`

However, `{ … }` is a `Refinement` (see `CompoundType`), which is not `SimpleType` unless parenthesised (see `‘(’ Types ‘)’`).

So, the parse tree of `({type λ[α] = Either[A, α]})#λ` is as follows:

```
      SimpleType ‘#’ id
          /           \
   ‘(’ Types ‘)’      'λ'
         |
        Type
         =
      InfixType
         =
    CompoundType
         =
     Refinement
```